# angularJS, i can't see the value of controller data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my template code

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
</li>
</ul>
```

and my js

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope','MYService', function($scope, MYService) {
$scope.names = [
                 {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
                 {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
                 {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
             ];
}]);
```

but my view shown result like this..

{,}

{,}

{,}

why can't not access the value?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or plunker and re-create the problem? it may help up see the problem better.

Comment: if i write this.. {{ $index + " , " + x.name +" ,"  + x.country }} is working!! but except $index , not working.. why??

Comment: [This simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5R7Z2/1/) shows it working just as intended. Maybe you're doing something strange with your MYService variable. Of course, that fiddle assumes you've set up your ng-app properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure that the current view can see `TestCtrl` controller for example.

```
<ul ng-controller="TestCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sure. i add the ng-controller="TestCtrl" at the body tag

Comment: what you are getting in console

Answer (score -1):

ng-controller should be used and mention the name.
This will be helpful
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

Comment: you can use the given link useful to debug your code and you should check before you mark it as The answer is not useful